# Equivalent of print "-"x20 of perl in Bash or command line

Tags: linux, macos, bash, command-line

In perl you can simply write print "-" x 20 and you get a line with dashes...but i need the same thing in bash/commandline on linux without perl/(g)awk etc. any ideas? The intention is to use it in the -exec of the find command and i want to prevent using simple echo "---------" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create you own function

```
customprint(){
  num=$1
  symbol=$2
  for((i=1;i<=$num;i++));do printf "%s" $symbol; done
}

customprint 20 "-"
```

or

```
customprint(){
  num=$1
  symbol=$2
  a=$(printf "%0${num}s")
  echo ${a// /$symbol}
}

customprint 20 "-"
```

or

```
num=20
eval printf '%.0s-' {1..$num}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `echo ${a//0/$symbol}`?

Comment: no, "%0<num>s" gives you blanks. only if you use "%0<num>d" will it give you leading 0's

Comment: The problem with own function is that i have to define it somewhere.

Comment: you can define it in your shell script. or a library and you source it when you want to use.

Comment: Interesting, `%0<num>s` gives me zeros on Mac OS X bash, Solaris bash/ksh, and HP-UX ksh; but spaces on Mac ksh. Don't have a Linux box handy though. Fun. `% ${num}s` seems to consistently give spaces though.

Answer (score 2):

So i have a little shorter solution

The following will produce a line with 60 dashes...without a function...

```
echo ={1..60} | sed  "s/[0-9]* \?//g"
```

Comment: in your question, you said without using Perl/awk, so now you are using sed ?

Comment: this is shorter, without using external tools: `eval printf '%.0s-' {1..$num}`

Comment: Yeah you're right. Your suggestions is cooler than mine. Thanks.